# Button which shows hidden <div> AND scrolls simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, I am trying to make a few buttons that show/hide a different "div".
I found a way in jQuery to make the button "homepage" show a hidden "div" and fade it in, but at the same time I want it to scroll down to a certain part of the page, for example: If I showed div2 but div1 was already visible, it would show both and SCROLL down to where div2 starts.

HTML:

```
    <button type="button" id="Home">Homepage</button>
    <div id="div1" class="div1">
    <h1> Welcome to the homepage! </h1>
    <h1> meh. </h1>
    <h1> meh. </h1>
    <h1> continue </h1>
    <h1> ---------- <h1>
    // I need to scroll here as soon as it loads/fades in
    // sort of like a simultanious button
    // The home button only loads it all in with jQ
    // BUT I need to scroll to this position at same time as load
    <h1> meh x2 </h1>
    <h1> finished </h1>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
    $('#Home').click(function() {
        $('#div1').toggle('fast', function() {
        });
    });
```

CSS:

```
    .div1 { display:none;}
```

To try and show this in a simpler way, view this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/onkz/qjd8v3hk/3/

If JavaScript makes this task easier then go ahead... I don't mind.
I am not a fan of messy code...
Oh, and if the scroll could be animated/smooth, that'd be even better!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("html, body").animate()` to use the animate function to change the scrolling position of the body. You can then use anchor objects or whatever you want to set where it scrolls to.

I've updated your jsfiddle, you can view it here. http://jsfiddle.net/qjd8v3hk/5/

Comment: Is this also possible in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Use an anchor, here, I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qjd8v3hk/4/

```
<button type="button" id="Home">Homepage</button>
    <div id="div1" class="div1">
        <h1> Welcome to the homepage! </h1>
        <h1> meh. </h1>
        <h1> meh. </h1>
        <h1> continue yay </h1>
        <h1> ---------- <h1>
I need to scroll here as soon as it loads/fades in
sort of like a simultanious button
The home button only loads it all in with jQ
BUT I need to scroll to this position at same time as load
        <h1> meh x2 </h1>
        <h1> meh x2 </h1>
        <h1> meh x2 </h1>
        <h1> meh x2 </h1>
        <h1> meh x2 </h1>
        <h1> meh x2 </h1>
        <h1> meh x2 </h1>
        <h1> meh x2 </h1>
        <h1> meh x2 </h1>
        <h1> meh x2 </h1>
        <h1> meh x2 </h1>
        <h1 id="go_here"> show me !!!!</h1>
        <h1> meh x2 </h1>
    </div>
```

and

```
$('#Home').click(function() {
    $('#div1').toggle('fast', function() {
        location.hash = "#go_here";
    });
});
```

Comment: This works, but only once. For some reason it breaks after the second press :/